# What is the difference between ServletContextListener and ServletRequestListener?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, listener

I want to put database connection into the listener by extracting the database parameter from `web.xml` . I know I have to put the connection into the ServletContextListener but can I put into the ServletRequestListener or atleast tell me where I should use ServletRequestListener?

I only want some little clarifications over it

Comment: A ServletContextListener gets called when your entire app starts up or goes down (not that often), a ServletRequestListener gets called for every single customer request (potentially thousands or even millions of times per minute, depending on traffic)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd So it is not good if I put the connection into servletRequestListener as it gets called many times.

Comment: I agree, that sounds like a very bad idea. servlet requests shouldn't know about db connections. but ideally I'd take it even further and make your entire web layer independent of the persistence layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ServletContextListener(at the time when context is initialized and destroyed)**

- If you want to perform some action at the time of deploying the web application then you should use ServletContextListener
- Where to use? Something like creating connection pool. in fact I have used it to store master table data(like country-list, countryWiseState lists etc.) in `hashmaps` and store those `hashmaps` in `application scope` and doing so, I reduced the unnecessary database fetches.

.

**ServletRequestListener(gets called when request in coming in and out of scope)**

- A ServletRequestListener can be implemented by the developer interested in being notified of requests coming in and out of scope in a web component. A request is defined as coming into scope when it is about to enter the first servlet or filter in each web application, as going out of scope when it exits the last servlet or the first filter in the chain.

Comment: thnks for your answer.

Comment: Please select it as the answer, if you found it useful.